# Grid View Column Display

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to display a number ascending order start from 1 to end of Grid view Row Count i try this but it only display the same number each row  a Grid view Column what did i miss

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{


    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=GridView1.Rows.Count; j++)

        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text = j.ToString();

        }

    }
```

Comment: haven't understood your question. what you are looking for?

Comment: i have a column ID on Grid View want to Display ID values when start from 1,2,3 .......GridView1.Rows.Count every time when a new data row is display

Comment: Do you want to show direct ids or Serial numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write code for this. You can use like below

```
 <Columns> 
     ... 
    <asp:TemplateField> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>. 
        </ItemTemplate> 
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" /> 
    </asp:TemplateField> 

</Columns>
```

Note this this column should be last column in your grid-view.